# Higher Order Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

How do you extend Fourier transforms beyond the 1-d case? I just learned about the transform and I am curious if anyone has some good information I can study over the summer.

Comment: This depends somewhat on your background.

Comment: My background is independent of your answer

Comment: That's true, but the question whether a certain recommendation is reasonable does depend on your background. But if you don't mind, try Rudin's Functional Analysis.